# Does the randomness of QM do much in everyday life? How much?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, soft-question, randomness

<sub>My apologies if in its current state this question isn't squarely suited here; I've worked it until it seemed reasonably articulate.  Feel free to move it if it'd be better received elsewhere.</sub>

According to quantum mechanics, the world is stochastic rather than deterministic, but I'm wondering whether this randomness is responsible for any real-world (macroscopic, easily observable) effects.  Over a short amount of time it shouldn't do much, but if two paths or timelines start diverging when an outcome turns out differently and continue to for long enough, I imagine it can, say, disturb a neuron, and the difference would eventually 'propagate' until it becomes something visible (to someone who knows what happens in the other world) such as boss giving me a raise when he would have fired me.

> 1)  Is this line of thinking correct?
>   2)  And -- more curious about this part -- if so, is there a way to quantify it with some (likely very crude) estimates of how fast the variation of sorts can be expected to grow?

Comment: Hi I Downvoted because this imo question is philosophy, I am sorry about that, but I just cannot imagine an instrument that could do the above, and it's not mainstream physics, with a consistent, repeatable, experimental setup. I honestly believe it would be better in the philosophy section of this site.

Comment: "*but I'm wondering whether this randomness is responsible for any real-world (macroscopic, easily observable) effects."*  QM (and then QFT) was *necessitated* in order to more closely model the *real-world* and, in particularly, produce predictions that approximated (with some spectacular successes) the outcome of *real-world* measurements.  So, it's quite possible I don't understand the finer point of your question.

Comment: Quantum Mechanics and its randomness indeed affect nearly everything, albeit in a relatively subtle way. It'd be rare that you'd directly see "randomness" itself, because the quantum world is so small that the literal randomness averages out very quickly. However, the same quantum mechanics and the same randomness fundamentally changes the properties of many materials (e.g. photovoltaics) and is what enables many devices to work (e.g. computers). Most of this particle level behavior is probably chaotic and subtle changes would diverge exponentially.

Comment: It is not the case that QM effects are "small" and have to "propagate" to become large. E.g. the fusion reaction in the sun is heavily reliant on QM tunneling probabilities, and it is certainly visible. I'm not sure what your actual question is.

Answer (score 1):

First off, quantum mechanics isn't "random". In QM, everything evolves perfectly deterministically, just in a somewhat strange way. Some people have the picture that a quantum mechanical universe looks just like a classical one, except that every once in a while crazy stuff randomly happens. Nope! It's not classical + randomness, it's a totally different system.

With that in mind, we should rephrase your question to "how much does approximating quantum mechanical systems as classical ones affect everyday life?"

Well, it turns out bulk matter and even individual atoms aren't stable unless you're working quantum mechanically. Even if you postulate material stability, chemistry won't work. Biology doesn't work. Light doesn't make sense. So QM affects everyday life a lot -- again, the universe is not classical plus quantum randomness, it *is* fundamentally quantum.

Let's say we ignore all those issues. We *still* can't tell because real systems are chaotic. That is, we wouldn't be able to predict what your brain will do to perfect accuracy even if the world were perfectly classical, since the tiniest of roundoff errors would accumulate.